# How to do cumulative and consecutive sums for every column in a tab file (UNIX environment)

Tags: bash, unix, for-loop, awk, sum

I have a tabulated file something like that

```
Q8VYA50 210     69      2       8       3
Q8VYA50 208     69      1       2       8       3
Q9C8G30 316     182     4       4       7
P335430 657     98      1       10      7
```

That I would like to do is to apply a cumulative sum from the 4rd column up to NF and print in every column the result of the sum for this column and the original value of previous columns if any. So that, the desired output would be

```
Q8VYA50 210     69      2       10      13
Q8VYA50 208     69      1       3       11       14
Q9C8G30 316     182     4       8       15
P335430 657     98      1       11      18
```

I have tried to do it through different ways by means of sum function inside an awk script including for-loop specifying the fields where must apply the cumulative sum. However, the result obtained is wrong.

Are there some way to do it correctly by Unix (Bash)? Thanks in advance!

This is one way I have tried to do @Inian

```
gawk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} {
            for (i=4;i<=NF;i++)
            {
                    sum[i]+=$i; print $1,$2,$3,$i
            }
```

}' "input_file"

Other way is to do for every column manually. $4,$5+$4,$6+$5+$4,$7+$6+$5+$4 and so on, but I think is a "seedy" method.

Comment: What did you try? Post your research efforts to the question

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @kvantour. I take account this explanation for the next question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk '{for(i=5;i<=NF;i++){$i+=$(i-1)}} 1' OFS="\t"  Input_file
```

Comment: It works correctly. Thanks @RavinderSingh13. I tried something similar but does not work correctly.